# Web Services - Internet Radio Directory

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I'm currently planning an app playing internet radio stations. Kindly share if there are any open web services which gives details of internet radio stations around on querying. If the response consists of url, currently playing or gives the response based on genre search or keyword search, it would really help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey I am interested in contributing this app for my knowledge building as i have imagined such application few month back but didn't find proper resources. let me know on developerjigar@gmail.com

Comment: Were you able to find any web services that provided a list of internet radio stations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked http://www.last.fm/api ???

Comment: ya. Found that while doing my homework. As far as i understand, lastfm wants us to use their own data coming from their servers. I'm looking for a open web service which gives a list of radio stations and their URLs. So we r free to make use of that URL our own way.